# Priority Queue Usage in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

I want to create a Priority Queue in Java such that I could enter a <Integer, Character> at each position. Here, higher the integer higher should be it's priority.

For example, let's say I have <20, 'A'>, <30, 'B'>, <40, 'C'>, if I dequeue I should get C (or <40, 'C'> whatever). I wish to use this once and then again enqueue <39, 'C'>. And so on until it ends at 90. (If the integers are equal, I don't care of the order.)

Despite several Google searches, I only find examples of adding an integer or a Class and having a comparator function. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Java doesn't have an official "tuple" type. Just define a holder class that has the `int` and a `char` you are grouping.

Comment: Well, a priority queue relies on the elements to be sortable by priority. So you'd need to enqueue objects that contain both the integer and the character as well as provide a comparator (or have the elements implement `Comparable`).

Comment: Can it be done without having to declare an explicit class since I just have a character and integer?